# Which are the fastest-paying literary magazines?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, magazines, sales

How fast a magazine pays is a function of several factors like their response time for stories they accept, their payment policy (eg., paying on acceptance as opposed to paying after publication), and their publication schedule. Thus there seems to be no actual data on it even in places like Duotrope. It seems that people can only really know based on experience. Is there anyone here who has enough experience with these literary magazines to know which are the fastest paying ones?

Comment: I don't think anyone really knows. "Fast" is a matter of perspective and opinion. And for policy and publication schedule you can probably just ask the magazines themselves.

Comment: Also, depends on the genre you're writing.

Answer (score 3):

This link at **All Freelance Writers  - Markets** lists not only markets, but (when possible) their turnaround time on pay.
https://allfreelancewriting.com/writers-markets/

With the "Fiction" limiter applied, only one appear to list turn-around time for pay (60 days after publication)
https://allfreelancewriting.com/writers-markets/?markets=Fiction&frm_search=

---

**The Submission Grinder** (https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Search/ByFilter ) allows you to search by response time -- when I put in 1c/word, and max 14-days, there were 83 responses -- of those about 60 were "no data" for Response Days, but that means about 20 were under 2 weeks!

---

Other SE Answer-ers: Any of y'all have Markets links that list pay info?